# Changing the home folder for ftp user in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I created ftp account through DotNetPanel and for some reason now it throws eror "hexadecimal value 0x03, is an invalid character.". However I noticed that an user has been created on the server and I am able to login through ftp client.

When I am logging in, it points to C:\inetpub\ftproot folder. Now I want to change the pointing folder so that I can point this user to my website folder and I can upload the files for my website.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

The "hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character"  error appears to be a common issue:

> The error "hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character" is known
>   to happen in DotNetPanel with Windows Server 2008 when web.config file
>   has been modified incorrectly or completely replaced. This is because
>   IIS 7 uses the web.config to store it's entire settings and any
>   incorrect modifications or complete replacement to this file will
>   cause the this error to happen
>
> 1. Make a note of all the virtual directories created for the website (virtual directory name and pointing path)
> 2. Remove the web.config file from the File Manager.
> 3. Delete the website from within DotNetPanel. (This will NOT delete any files of the website).
> 4. Re-add the website.
> 5. Setup all the virtual directories again.

To change the home directory of the user, from the [DotNetPanel Guide](http://www.dotnetpanel.com/documentation/DotNetPanel%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf):

> Home directory location  Select “Folder in your Hosting Space” option
>   to point web site to some folder within the hosting space.  You could
>   change web site root folder from default one “wwwroot” if it was
>   allowed in the hosting plan.  Select “Redirection to URL” to redirect
>   all requests from client application, such as web browser, to  another
>   Web site or virtual directory by entering a URL in the box below.